# T-SQL TRIGGER return 1 more "Rows Affected" Than expected when INSERT data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a secondary key. Before inserting, I want to check if this secondary key exists in another table as primary key.

To do this I've create a trigger in T-SQL on this table. Here it is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_tb_repair_order_before] 
ON [dbo].[tb_repair_order]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @or_code NVARCHAR(50) 
    DECLARE @or_designation NVARCHAR(300)
    DECLARE @or_comment NVARCHAR(3000)
    DECLARE @code_customer NVARCHAR(50)

    DECLARE cur_tb_repair_order_before CURSOR FOR 
         SELECT or_code, or_designation, or_comment, code_customer 
         FROM inserted

    OPEN cur_tb_repair_order_before

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_tb_repair_order_before INTO @or_code, @or_designation, @or_comment, @code_customer

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF ((SELECT  Count(*) FROM tb_customer WHERE code = @code_customer) > 0) 
        BEGIN
            IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) > 0)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO tb_repair_order (or_code, or_designation, or_comment, code_customer)
                VALUES (@or_code, @or_designation, @or_comment, @code_customer)
            END
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_tb_repair_order_before INTO @or_code, @or_designation, @or_comment, @code_customer
    END

    CLOSE cur_tb_repair_order_before
    DEALLOCATE cur_tb_repair_order_before
END
```

Everything is good, this trigger works perfectly.

The problem is the number of rows inserted

[Here is result for wrong secondary key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRLa4.png)

As we can see, SQL returns "1 rows affected" but nothing is inserted into the table ...

[Here is result for good secondary key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKkN6.png)

And here SQL returns "2 rows affected".

If someone can explain how I can return the correct result because in my C# code the `ExecuteNonQuery` function returns not the expected result and it's bad practice to continue with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never a good idea to use a cursor in a trigger (performance killer).  
Also, when you do use cursors, always declare as FAST_FORWARD unless you can't... an in this case you can.

Comment: This can and should be a single insert statement that inserts all those rows at once.

Comment: Why do you need to check if it exists in the other table? Why not just use key constraints? Then there's no need for a trigger.

Comment: Yes of course i can use key counstraint for a simple thing but did you know how can i get the good number with Rows affected and why here is 1 extra rows affected in this situation?

Comment: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.